# The following packages don't support null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, sqflite, dart-null-safety

How to run with the null safety using the following packages

- package:sqflite
- package:sqflite_common
- package:synchronized

Code:

```
void database() async {
// ignore: unused_local_variable
var database = await openDatabase('alimaher.db', version: 1,
    onCreate: (database, vervion) {
  // ignore: avoid_print
  print('database created');
  database
      .execute(
          'CREATE TABLE tasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT, date TEXT,time TEXT,status TEXT ) ')
      .then((value) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print('table created');
  }).catchError((error) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print('error when creating table ${error.toString()}');
  });
}, onOpen: (database) {
  // ignore: avoid_print
  print('database opened');
});
```

}

The error message:

> Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety:
>
> - package:sqflite
> - package:sqflite_common
> - package:synchronized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three packages **do** support sound null-safety in their latest releases.

You did not show your pubspec.yaml, but I guess you will need to **update** those packages to their most recent versions.

Comment: my packages is in the last version :

Comment: I agree, all these package support null safety, maybe you are getting other log error?

Answer (score 0):

Either update packages to last versions or build with `--no-sound-null-safety` argument

Comment: I already updated the packages  but not run